# VBA to make range("K1") = a slicer item value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, slicers

I have a search box (K1) that will search through slicer items and display the appropriate chart, however, the value in K1 will not match the slicer item if the user chooses to use the slicer to show a particular chart.

The only time they match is when the user uses the search box. I created a formula in cell O1 that returns a 1 (if they match) or a 0 if they do not match, and then tried different variations of making K1 = to item value (the quoted part of the code).

Please see my link to the dashboard image  for reference.

[image: dashboard image]

I'm very new to VBA, so any ELI5 answers would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SearchPivots()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

On Error GoTo 28


'Find Pivot Table
Set pt = Worksheets("Overall Pivot").PivotTables("NAMERPM")

Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Filter Field")
NewCat = Worksheets("Resource Dashboard").Range("K1").Value

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
    pt.RefreshTable
End With

'With Field
'    If Range("O1").Value = 0 Then
'        Range("K1") = Field.CurrentPage.Value
'    End If
'End With

    Exit Sub
28:
    MsgBox "That project number is not listed.  Please check the project number and try again."

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Tony, at this link you'll find a hack that lets you do this with no VBA whatsoever. http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/

Comment: Thank you, Jeffrey.  I'm going to check that out.  :)

Comment: @jeffreyweir Jeffrey, the link is broken. Can you please post your hack. Can you look at related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945719/read-all-selected-slicer-item-values-to-an-array-variable

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding the question, how does a slicer control which chart is shown, but the code below will get the selected slicer items by way of a pivottable change event (but of course they could select many)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim sItem As Excel.SlicerItem
Dim msg As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim i As Long

    nextrow = 0
    For i = 1 To Target.Slicers.Count

        msg = Target.Slicers(i).Name & vbNewLine

        For Each sItem In Target.Slicers(i).SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItems

            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            msg = msg & vbTab & sItem.Name & vbNewLine
        Next sItem

        MsgBox msg
    Next i
End Sub
```

Referencing a particular slicer by name

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim sItem As Excel.SlicerItem
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String

    nextrow = 0

    With Target.Slicers("Filter_Field")

        msg = .Name & vbNewLine

        For Each sItem In .SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItems

            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            msg = msg & vbTab & sItem.Name & vbNewLine
        Next sItem

        MsgBox msg
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bob - thanks for your information.  The slicer is tied to a pivot table that is tied to the chart's filter field.  So, a user can enter a project number in K1 and click search; the only thing is, if they use the slicer, K1 doesn't update to the slicer item value which confuses the audience since a legacy project number is still showing.  Does that make sense?  I'll try your code, but would this go on a sheet or a module?

Comment: It would go in the sheet that has the pivot Tony as it is event code. If it looks okay, you will need to remove the MsgBox, and then set cell K1 to that selected value.

Comment: I did that, but now it's showing the name of another slicer.  How do I get it to point to the slicer in question ("Slicer_Filter_Field")?

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: My code iterates through every slicer attached to a pivot, if you want just one you can specify that one.

Slicer_Filter_Field is the formula name, the name is probably Filter_Field. You would replace the index with the name
    
I can't figure out how to add code to a comment so I have added it to my original answer.

Comment: Tony, I am struggling to understand how iterating through the slicer items returns the slicer name. Any chance you could post the workbook somewhere for me to look at?

Comment: Hi Bob, yes but I'm not sure how to post it here.

Comment: If you put it in a share site, I use cjoint.com which is in French but Google will translate, and post the link. Or use something like DropBox, OneDrive, or Hightail and share the link.

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry about the delay.  I put it on my onedrive.  Hopefully, you can view it.  Please let me know of any questions.  Once again, I very much appreciate your help.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B63EED09F7075AE4!3869&authkey=!AJBp3cd0tHVfjDU&ithint=file%2cxlsm

Comment: Hello Tony, I have just tried your app and it seems to work fine to me ... but ... you might be looking in the wrong place. The slicer selected item is being placed in cell B1 on the 'Region and RU Dashboard' sheet. If you are expecting to see it on the 'Resource Dashboard' sheet you need to write it there (if you deepen row 1 you will see it has the slicer name and selected value from the Overall Pivot). I notice that you have another slicer on that sheet, which is not linked to the pivots. If you connect them to the pivots, both sheets will be synchronised in their slicer selection.

Comment: If you want the two sheets to be independent, one from Overall, one from Region & RU, connect the slicers appropriately, your code looks fine. But make row 1 deeper on both sheets.

Comment: Thank you so very much, Bob.  You've been a tremendous help!  :)