# Read all selected slicer item values to an array variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, slicers

How to read all selected slicer item values to an array variable? I thought this might work:

```
Dim MyArr() as Variant
MyArr = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).VisibleSlicerItemsList
```

But it does not. Some reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercache.visiblesliceritemslist

Answer (score 0):

You can't use VisibleSlicerItemsList, unless you are using an OLAP data source.
From the documentation:

> The **VisibleSlicerItemsList** property is only applicable for slicers that are based on OLAP data sources.

I think the easiest way is to iterate over VisibleSlicerItems.